# Upgrading NodeJS version to Node 14 from Node10 LTS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, spdy

I am trying to upgrade one of the legacy Angular 1.6 app running on Node v8.12.0 to at least Node v12.18.4 or v14 LTS.
I have been able to do a sequential upgrade from v8.12.0 to v10.18.0. But now when I m trying to upgrade from v10.18.0 to v12.18.4 or v14 of Node, I am getting

```
RangeError: Invalid typed array length: -4095
at new Uint8Array (<anonymous>)
at new FastBuffer (internal/buffer.js:945:1)
at Handle.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:185:19)
at Stream.<anonymous> (/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/handle-thing/lib/handle.js:120:12).
```

I tried various Github issues resolution but so far I could not get it to work .
Is there any other node package I can use instead of "spdy" package that uses handle-thing node module as its dependency and causes error?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: which version of handle-thing do you have? have you updated it - looks like this closed issue https://github.com/spdy-http2/handle-thing/issues/6

Comment: I followed it, have 2.0.1. Still doesnt work